# How to find and replace specific words on a 2013 Community Site?

Tags: javascript, branding, community-site

When you create a new Community site, you'll see the Discussion list. Just above that is a button where it says "new discussion". Below that is a view called "My discussions". See screenshot below.

Our client would like to have the word `"discussion"` changed into `"ad"` (*because they want it to be a buy/sell place*).

So `"new discussion"` needs to become `"new ad"` and `"My discussions"` needs to become `"My ads"`. I only want this change on this specific Community site, not on all other or newly created Community sites.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I understand javascript might be a good option. What would the code be? How and where would I insert that? I would also need to change this on the `Categorie.aspx` page because there too appears the word `"discussion"` or `"discussions"`.

Any other solutions/recommendations? Your help would be very much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jQuery and script editor web part.

- Edit Page from site setting
- Click Add Web Part
- Click Media and Content
- Click Script Editor
- Click Add button
- Click EDIT SPIPPET

Paste following code in the dialog box

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newDiscussion = $('.ms-comm-heroLinkContainer a span:not([class])');
    newDiscussion.innerHTML = "new add";
    var myDiscussions = $('#clientPivotControl0_surfaceopt1');
    myDiscussions.innerHTML = "My adds";
});
```

I have tested above code. In your case, elements may be different. So put the appropriate element selector in the code. For any confusion, ask me in comment. Make sure jQuery is in your site already!